# Scrollable chips flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I've Created the chips but I want them to be horizontally  scrollable and control the data to be shown based on the chip selected
For the time being I've been able to create the chips and the scrollable colors below them but now i want to combine both of them
I want the chips to be scrollable and control the data shown below them and a see all to list the full data

My code till now

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mad_ezee_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart';
       // child: PageView(
        //     controller: pageController,
        //     children: [
        //       Container(color: Colors.red,),
        //       Container(color: Colors.blue,),
        //       Container(color: Colors.white,),
        //       Container(color: Colors.yellow,),
        //     ],
        //   ),
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  PageController pageController = PageController();
  List array =["choice 1","choice 2","choice 3","choice 4","choice 5"];
  void onTapped(int index){
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
    pageController.jumpToPage(index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children:[
              Container(
                  child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top:45,bottom: 15),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,right: 20),
                      child:Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                                children:[
                                  Text("Bengaluru"),
                                  Text("R.T Nagar")
                                ]
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 45,
                              height:45,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0,right: 0),
                              child: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.white,),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                  color:TimePassColor.APP_COLOR
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: 45,
                              height:45,
                              child: Icon(Icons.notifications,color: Colors.white,),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                  color:TimePassColor.APP_COLOR
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]
                      )
                  )
              ),
              ListView(
                primary: true,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Wrap(
                    spacing: 4.0,
                    runSpacing: 0.0,
                    children: List<Widget>.generate(
                      array.length, // place the length of the array here
                      (int index) {
                        return Chip(
                          label: Text(array[index])
                        );
                      }
                    ).toList(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                child:ListView(
            // This next line does the trick.
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 160.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 160.0,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 160.0,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 160.0,
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 160.0,
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: PageView(
                  controller: pageController,
                  children: [
                    Container(color: Colors.red,),
                    Container(color: Colors.blue,),
                    Container(color: Colors.white,),
                    Container(color: Colors.yellow,),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ]
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem> [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home),label:'Home'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.cleaning_services),label:'House Keeping'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search),label:'Search'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet),label:'Wallet'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.bookmarks),label:'Bookmarked'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.local_convenience_store),label:'Store'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),label:'Notifications'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.assessment),label:'Notifications'),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person),label:'Profile'),
        ],currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.grey,
          onTap: onTapped,
        )
    );
  }
}
```

***My current output looks like the below image***
[image]

***I'm new to flutter so feel free to ask any questions in comments regarding the question clearification.***

Answer (score 1):

replace your `chips` `ListView` with `SingleChildScrollView`,
instead of:

```
ListView(
            primary: true,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              Wrap(
                spacing: 4.0,
                runSpacing: 0.0,
                children: List<Widget>.generate(
                  array.length, // place the length of the array here
                  (int index) {
                    return Chip(
                      label: Text(array[index])
                    );
                  }
                ).toList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

try this:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Row(
                        children: List<Widget>.generate(
                            array.length, // place the length of the array here
                                (int index) {
                              return Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: (){
                                    //Call a function to update your UI
                                  },
                                  child: Chip(
                                      label: Text(array[index])
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                        ).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: And how do i use these chips to control the data to be shown below them?

Comment: I have upvoted as it has solved half of my issue

Comment: So you want to update the UI below the chips according to the selected child?

Comment: Thats true @Abdallah A. Odeh

Comment: You can wrap your `Chip` with a `GestureDetector` to get a click event on every chip, I've update my answer

Comment: chips aren't clickable yet and they are not doing anything still

Comment: That's why we use 'em inside a `GestureDetector` or `InkWell`, to detect user touches, try to put a `print(index);` inside the `onTap` method and it will print the clicked index for you